# How to find matching length of matching elements having same xpath in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium and want to find the length of the nodes with matching xpath.

eg:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr><td></td></tr>
              <tr><td></td></tr>
              <tr><td></td></tr>
              <tr><td></td></tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
    </body>
```

I want to write a java code in Selenium to find the length of the node. I want the length for example if i am finding the **"tr"** node i want it length to be 4

xpath will be .//html/body/table/tr

Comment: tried to find the length using a
 Dimension accounts = allocation.findElement(By.xpath("td[2]/table/tbody/tr")).getSize();

But dimensions is not giving proper values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` is incorrect. You should also use `findElements` in plural to find more than one element. This will return `List<WebElement>` and then you can simply call `size()` to get the number of `<tr>` tags. Try

```
int count = allocation.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr")).size();
```

I gave absolute path since there aren't and other identifiers in the html you provided, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: i am able to get the length of the xpath specified thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

In java,

### For counting row size,

```
int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='DataTable01']/tbody/tr")).size();
```

### For counting column size,

```
int columnCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='DataTable01']/tbody/tr/td")).size();
```

You can do it another way,

```
List<WebElement> rows = tblData.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
int rowCount  = rows.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put `//` if you are traversing from the very parent node.

Below xpath will work for you too

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr
```

**Absolute XPath**
Absolute XPath starts with the root node or a forward slash (/).
The advantage of using absolute is, it identifies the element very fast.
Disadvantage here is, if any thing goes wrong or some other tag added in between, then this path will no longer works.

Example:
If the Path we defined as

```
1. html/head/body/table/tbody/tr/th
```

If there is a tag that has added between body and table as below

```
2. html/head/body/form/table/tbody/tr/th
```

The first path will not work as 'form' tag added in between

**Relative XPath**

A relative XPath is one where the path starts from the node of your choise - it doesn't need to start from the root node.

It starts with Double forward slash(`//`)

Syntax:

```
//table/tbody/tr/th
```

Advantage of using relative xpath is, you don't need to mention the long xpath, you can start from the middle or in between.

Disadvantage here is, it will take more time in identifying the element as we specify the partial path not (exact path).

If there are multiple elements for the same path, it will select the first element that is identified